# How to get node by attribute value with special char?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<group name="testy_&quot;group&quot;_1515083335">
</group>
```

How to get group node by attribute "name" value?

This is not working:

```
//group[@name='testy_&quot;group&quot;_1515083335']
```

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpf works fine for me.

Comment: Please explain in what way the expression is "not working"? Do you get an error? If so, which one? You have tagged your question as both xpath and xslt, in the context of an XSLT stylesheet the path expression should select the element you have posted. If you use pure XPath inside a programming language which is not XML then simply use double quotes `"` instead of `&quot;`, perhaps making sure you escape them as needed in Javascript or C#.